# Access class variable from std::thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I have the following class which kicks off a new std::thread.  I now want the thread to access a member variable of the class.  So far I cannot work out how to do this.
In my MyThread function I want to check m_Continue.

I have tried passing in 'this' when the thread is created but I get an error:

**Error 1   error C2197: 'void (__cdecl *)(void)' : too many arguments for call c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\functional   1152    1   MyProject**.

```
class SingletonClass
{
public:
    SingletonClass();
    virtual ~SingletonClass(){};

    static SingletonClass& Instance();
   void DoSomething();
private:
    static void MyThread();

    std::thread* m_Thread;
    bool m_Continue;
};

SingletonClass::SingletonClass()
{
    m_Continue = true;
    m_Thread= new std::thread(MyThread, this);
}

void SingletonClass::MyThread()
{
    while(this->m_Continue )
    {
       // do something
    }
}

void SingletonClass::DoSomething()
{
    m_Continue = false;
}

SingletonClass& SingletonClass::Instance()
{
    static SingletonClass _instance;
    return _instance;
}


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    SingletonClass& singleton = SingletonClass::Instance();
    singleton.DoSomething();    

    return 0;
}
```

**How can I do this??**

Comment: Unrelated: there's no reason to allocate the thread dynamically, `m_thread` could simply be a `std::thread` that you assign: `m_thread = std::thread{MyThread, this};`. Also, your program has undefined behavior due to a data race on `SingletonClass::m_Continue` since it can potentially be accessed in the spawned thread while simultaneously being modified in the main thread. You need to either make it a `std::atomic<bool>` or protect accesses to it with a `std::mutex`.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to access `this` from within the thread function, then it shouldn't be static:

```
void MyThread();
```

Now you can simply pass `this` as the second `thread` constructor argument, as you tried; but, being a non-static member, you'll need to qualify its name:

```
m_Thread= new std::thread(&SingletonClass::MyThread, this);
```

Alternatively, you might find a lambda easier to read:

```
m_Thread= new std::thread([this]{MyThread();});
```

But you shouldn't muck around with pointers and `new` like that; make the member variable a `thread` object and initialise it in the initialiser list:

```
SingletonClass::SingletonClass() :
    m_Continue(true), m_Thread([this]{MyThread();})
{}
```

making sure to declare `m_Thread` after any other members that it accesses; and make sure you stop and join the thread in the destructor, or earlier.

Finally, `m_Continue` should be `std::atomic<bool>` in order to set it on one thread and read it on another with well-defined behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

Replace

`static void MyThread();`

with

`void MyThread();`

as

`this` cannot be access within `static` method.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the member variable if it is public or you may make have a method like "bool shallContinue()" which returns m_Continue.

Now how do you do this. Check the below modified snippet:

```
static void SingletonClass::MyThread(SingleTonClass *arg)
{
    while(arg->shallContinue() )
    {
       // do something
    }
}
```

Below a complete example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <unistd.h>
using namespace std;

class A
{
public:
    A(int x) : a(x) 
    {
        thr = new thread(myThread, this);
    }
    static void myThread(A *arg)
    {
        arg->show();

    }
    void show()
    {
        cout << a << endl;
    }
private:
    int a;
    thread *thr;
};

int main()
{
    A a(1);
    sleep(2); 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can access it from a member function whether or not it's public. And why would you use a `void*` argument when you can just make it non-static?

Comment: That was just quick typing. There are many ways to achieve this actually making static, non-static etc.